# C# and VB.NET LDAP Search Different?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, exception, ldap

Does anyone know if there is a difference between the implementation of the FindAll() method on the DirectorySearcher object in C# and VB.NET? From my understanding they both get "compiled" to MSIL and get processed by the CLR the same way. Going against our ADAM/LDAP system the below C# code throws an error and the below VB.NET does not.

Here is the C# exception stack:

```
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll()
```

Here is the C# error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
Message="The parameter is incorrect.\r\n"
Source="System.DirectoryServices"
ErrorCode=-2147024809
```

C# code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://directory.corp.com/OU=Person,OU=Lookups,O=Corp,C=US", null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous);
    DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(root);

    mySearcher.Filter = "(uid=ssnlxxx)";
    mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
    mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

    SearchResultCollection searchResultCollection = null;
    searchResultCollection = mySearcher.FindAll(); //this is where the error occurs

    try
    {
        foreach (SearchResult resEnt in searchResultCollection)
        {
            Console.Write(resEnt.Properties["cn"][0].ToString());
            Console.Write(resEnt.Properties["mail"][0].ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect LDAP domain, Check username or password to get user details.");
    }
}
```

This is the VB.NET code that works:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim root As New     DirectoryEntry("LDAP://directory.corp.com/OU=People,OU=Lookups,O=corp,C=US", vbNull, vbNull, authenticationType:=DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous)
    Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(root)
    searcher.Filter = "(uid=ssnlxxx)"
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail")

    Dim results As SearchResultCollection

    Try
        results = searcher.FindAll()

        Dim result As SearchResult
        For Each result In results
            Console.WriteLine(result.Properties("cn")(0))
            Console.WriteLine(result.Properties("mail")(0))
        Next result
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: I'm not sure this will address your issue _(so I'm commenting and not 'answering...')_ but in your c# code you might change `"LDAP://directory.corp.com/OU=Person,OU=Lookups,O=Corp,C=US"` to `@"LDAP://directory.corp.com/OU=Person,OU=Lookups,O=Corp,C=US"`. The @ symbol tells the the C# compiler to ignore escape characters, this is one of the few differences between C# and VB.NET that might directly affect this issues.

Comment: What's the `vbNull` thing in the VB.NET code? Is this different to `Nothing`?

Comment: I also notice you're catching a different exception between the two languages. Try catching the same exception and see if you don't get the same result.

Comment: vbNull is the value that VarType returns to indicate that a variant is has no type. It's not equivalent to c# NULL - use vb keyword Nothing for that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried putting an '@' infront of the URI. Same error. I also tried moving the creation of the searcher under the try. Same error. I also tried catching the same exception. Same error. Any other ideas? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Cos, there are no backslashes in the string, so the `@` won't make any difference.

Comment: @Joe, I always get my slashes wrong...Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I am going to guess that in the VB.NET code, you're passing in `vbNull` (instead of `Nothing`) for two parameters in the `DirectoryEntry` constructor, and in the C# code you're passing `null`. `vbNull` is presumably from the evil `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly which should not be used.

The constructor for `DirectoryEntry` checks the username and password parameters to see if they're null. If `vbNull != Nothing`, the constructor won't treat them as null and will behave differently.

See if the VB.NET code throws the exception if you use `Nothing`, or alternatively see if the C# code works by using `String.Empty` instead of `null`.

Also, in your C# code, the call to `FindAll` is outside of the try block.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful. I will give your suggestions a shot.

Comment: You solved it! Changing the nulls in the constructor of the DirectoryEntry object to String.Empty solved the problem. The COM layer must not like nulls. It must need an empty string. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user477871 Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am glad you got your answer, please take a moment and "Accept" @Graham's answer to recognize his assistance to you. Take a few moments and familiarize yourself with the FAQs http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

Neither C# nor VB.NET implement `DirectorySearcher` or any other part of .NET. They are all part of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Thanks. I realize that ultimately this functionality is in the framework not the language. Similar to java and the JVM. This doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: You asked if there is a "difference between the implementation of the FindAll() method on the DirectorySearcher object in C# and VB.NET". The answer is "no, because that object is in .NET, not in C# or VB.NET". So if there's a difference between your two code samples, it's something else.